# Pinterest : setUrl for setImageUri

Tags: android, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

```
mButtonPinIt = (PinItButton) view.findViewById(R.id.pin_button);
mButtonPinIt.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(mFile.getAbsoluteFile())); 
mButtonPinIt.setUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

By taking Image from sdCard, webUrl is not setting in Pinterest Application. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you declearation Internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes.I did.Also,When taking the image from website( Eg:setImageUrl("http://placekitten.com/500/400") ) then webUrl set in Pinterest Apllication.

Comment: Instead of using setImageUri ,if I use setImageUrl then SetUrl works otherwise it will not work.All though it will not give any type of exception

Comment: We're experiencing the same behavior. I've filed a bug with Pinterest, we'll see what comes of it.

Comment: @bensnider how was it?

Comment: @LeiLeyba I got an initial response from Pinterest but didn't get a follow up stating if they fixed it or not. My original ticket was closed. So I don't know if it was ever resolved.